# Create group price based on markup from cost

Tags: magento-1.9, pricing

I want to set a group price by adding a percentage to the cost of a product(s) in my store.

Is there a way to do this **without** adding an extension?

How can I achieve this programmatically?

**SR_Magento EDIT:**

The answer to this questions appears to lie in the table `catalog_product_entity_group_price`

By manually creating a group price for a product, I was able to create additional group prices based on the original example:
[image]

It stands to reason that it is possible to do this programmatically by creating a markup **cost** + **x%** and then populate the field "**value**". The *entity_id* is the products Magento ID, the *customer_group_id* is the ID of the Group you wish to give special pricing.

**Bounty expires in 2 days, if I don't get at least an SQL statement I can work with I will let it expire.**

Comment: Can I assume you want your selling price to be some percentage more than your cost ?

Comment: Yes. I am using this for selling store to store. I have other retailers that buy from me and they get a cost plus 10% price.

Comment: Any luck?, I'm looking for the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

This solution requires you know a little SQL to accomplish what you want, but I think it's along the lines of what SR_Magento is thinking.

In this example, I assume you have one website so I default website_id and all_groups to 0, I use 2 as the customer_group but feel free to update this to your customer group id that you are using.

I set the group price to cost plus 10%.  You can change the percentage by update (value/10) and setting 10 to your new percentage.

Attribute_id of 100 in the catalog_product_entity_decimal table should be your product costs.  This is all one mysql query, tested and working on my dev site prior to formatting it here:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_group_price(
    entity_id, 
    value,  
    customer_group_id, 
    all_groups, website_id)    

  SELECT entity_id, 
     value + (value/10) as value, 
     2 as customer_group_id, 
     0 as all_groups, 
     0 as website_id

  FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal 

  WHERE entity_type_id=10 
     AND attribute_id=100 
     AND value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you install http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-debug.html you can see the query that Magento runs when you manually set the price.  That will give you the SQL code you want.

Comment: That looks like a nifty tool, wasnt aware of it thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score -1):

To A) No, you cannot. And extension is, what you need.

B) You can achieve this programatically (with an extension).First thing I found on google is this one. The description reads as if would do the job:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cost-based-pricing.html

Bb) you have to be more clear about how you want to define cost+x = price.
Is that for ALL Articles? For a Category? For a certain Attribute Type?

Leading to C) get the extension. If it's insufficent, extend the extension. It'll be much less hussle the building you own extension.

Comment: And yes, you could write that your own and no, you cannot do that below the price of the module.

Comment: What is this Google you speak of? Please read the Bounty **Need a solution to create group pricing programmatically for all products**

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: This is definitely achievable without a module.

Comment: Sure @SR_Magento, you could to something like a setPrice on save event if product exitsts. Techically this would be also ok with just extending locally. But will you be lucky with that? A fixed raise over all products?